# Svelte: Change classes of checked checkbox (without creating variable for checkbox)

Tags: javascript, checkbox, svelte

I am kind of new to **Svelte** and trying to solve this *(seemingly trivial)* problem with my UI:

I would like to change the classes of a checkbox and/or its parent element when the checkbox is checked. The Svelte docs tell me to create a boolean var for every checkbox and bind activation the classes to it: *https://svelte.dev/tutorial/class-shorthand*

but I have a random amount of checkboxes and many different types of checkboxes with different behaviour in styling and I don't want to create (or generate) a variable for every single checkbox.

**Is there any elegant way in Svelte for changing the classes of checkboxes when they are indivually checked? (vanilla javascript instead if jquery if possible :) )**

Cheers
Some Svelte noob

Answer (score 2):

For something like this I would use... `use`, or [actions](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/actions). You can add/remove the class/classes using vanilla JS.

Since the class doesn't actually exist in the component you'll get an error if you define the class in your component unless you use `:global()`and even when doing that if you've set a property of CSS you'll need to make sure the [specificity](https://specificity.keegan.st/) of the global selector is higher than the class generated by Svelte (i.e. `:global(div.class)`)

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4395ab87445d469b85f2e8bb11fab2f4?version=3.30.1) showing it in action with a few checkboxes and no need for variables or id's.

Comment: I hope you still around so you can answer my question regarding this solution. It's such a beautiful solution with use/actions. I'm wondering if It can be modified to limit the number of checkbox selection?

Comment: Hi @Marco it honestly depends on what your individual use-case is. The poster of this question seemed to not need to track the checked boxes in the state of the app but you may need that (this solution simply changes the styling of an element). I would say you can post a new question that describes your need, what you've tried, and what outcome you'd like in detail. I am sure someone would be able to solve it easily (there's plenty of ways with Svelte).

Comment: I have been struggling for one week now and almost giving up on using svelte all together but I love using it.  This is what I'm trying to do  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928488/need-help-using-object-fromentries-to-reorganize-an-array-of-objects-the-fun-st/72928654?noredirect=1#comment128812575_72928654

Comment: Loop over the options in that object, create a form with checkboxes, user choose options (rules and rules number is to limit the selection according to that number) and collect user selection and process the form. I know how to do everything else except how to limit/prevent the user from going over the selection limit.

Comment: @Marco this question mentions nothing about Svelte... Do you have a REPL showing what you have tried in Svelte? You can use the example of what the object array you get from your database looks like that you shared in that question as a local variable and recreate what your setup is. But I would strongly advise if you need help with Svelte that you re-ask the question in a Svelte-specific way showing what you markup and JS looks like.

Comment: This is my latest attempt. I have options coming from db. I use each block and created the form. I also used Object.fromEntries(map()) to create an object for each group to bind:group to it.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72945098/2way-binding-is-not-responding-to-clicking-in-svelte?noredirect=1#comment128840956_72945098

Comment: and this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808622/limiting-the-number-of-checkbox-in-svelte-form-using-disabled-attribute-with-mor/72810473#72810473

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have said, I would create a subcomponent to wrap the checkbox.
Lets Call it ToggleCheck. And if you want a div around each checkbox, then the div would live inside of of the ToggleCheck component

Then each instance of ToggleCheck would have its own var.

Your parent component could then have one or many instances of , even within a loop.

Comment: How to limit the number of selection for those loop of checkboxes component? I'm struggling to understand how to limit the number of selection using checkbox group.