# 2way binding is not responding to clicking in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I've been struggling with this issue for a week. I didn't know how to structure my checkbox but H.B. showed me the way and explained everything.

I was able to understand how to structure my data and setup the form except now I see the binding is one way. When I tested the solution from HB it was with mock data I created to explain the situation. In the real world the data is coming from db.

Let me explain:
I have group of options that the user use to make selections. Every group of options has its own limit.

So the solution was to create an object with option groups header/name and bind that in my checkbox group. Please observe the bind:group in for checkbox input.

```
form name="options" on:submit|preventDefault={()=>collectoptions(itemid, itemprice, itemname,  itemdescription, variationname, variationprice)}>

  {#each displayoptions as option}
 
      {#if option['rules'] == "exactly"}
        <p>exactly limit number : {option.rulesnumber.number} - {option._id}</p> 
        <p>Group Name :{option.groupheader}</p>  
        {#each option.optiongroupitems as optionitem}
          <li style="list-style : none;">
              <label>
                <input name={option.groupheader} type="checkbox" bind:group={finalgroupit[option.groupheader]} value={optionitem.name} disabled={finalgroupit[option.groupheader].length === option.rulesnumber.number && finalgroupit[option.groupheader].some(x => x[0].name == optionitem.name) == false} /> 
                {optionitem.name} : {optionitem.price}
              </label>      
          </li>
        {/each}  
      {/if}

      {#if option['rules'] == "minimum"}
        <p>minimum limit number : {option.rulesnumber.number} - {option._id}</p> 
        <p>Group Name :{option.groupheader}</p> 
          {#each option.optiongroupitems as optionitem}
              <li style="list-style : none;">
                <label>
                    <input name={option.groupheader} type="checkbox" bind:group={finalgroupit[option.groupheader]} value={optionitem.name} disabled={finalgroupit[option.groupheader].length === option.rulesnumber.number} /> 
                    {optionitem.name} : {optionitem.price}
                </label>      
              </li>
          {/each}
      {/if}

      {#if option['rules'] == "maximum"}
      <p>maximum limit number : {option.rulesnumber.number} - {option._id}</p>  
      <p>Group Name :{option.groupheader}</p> 
        {#each option.optiongroupitems as optionitem}
            <li style="list-style : none;">
              <label>
                  <input name={option.groupheader} type="checkbox" bind:group={finalgroupit[option.groupheader]} value={optionitem.name} disabled={finalgroupit[option.groupheader].length > option.rulesnumber.number} /> 
                  {optionitem.name} : {optionitem.price}
              </label>      
            </li>
        {/each}
      {/if}   
  <button type="submit" >Add To cart</button>
</form>
```

When I posted my previous question it was with a mock data to make sure my question is clear but now my data is coming from a db and I get it with a fetch in onMount lifecycle function like this:

```
<script>
    onMount(async () => {      
    
        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/getitemoptions',{
      method: 'POST',
      origin : 'http://localhost:5000',
      credentials : 'include',
      headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-type' : 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
       id : itemid
      })
    
      }) //fetch
    
      let serverdata = await response.json()
      displayoptions = serverdata.item.options
      finalgroupit = displayoptions  
       finalgroupit = Object.fromEntries(displayoptions.map(g => [g.groupheader,  []]));  
       finalgroupit = finalgroupit
       
       }) //onMount  

  let displayoptions = [] 
  $: showproceedbutton = false
  $: displayoptionsoutside = []
  let finalgroupit = []

  for (let value of Object.entries(finalgroupit)) {
         console.log("log for object.entries :", value)
        console.log("entries 0 :", value[0])
        console.log("entries 1 :", value[1])
  }
</script>
```

When I make the selection everything performs as expected - that means once the user make the correct number of selections by clicking on the checkbox - the rest of the selection is disabled. But the binding is two ways so if the user try to change the selection, he/she will be able to uncheck and recheck the selection.

I'm able to make the selection but once the disable is activated, I'm unable to uncheck the selection. I assume because the binding is not working. Because when I test with local data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808622/limiting-the-number-of-checkbox-in-svelte-form-using-disabled-attribute-with-mor/72810473?noredirect=1#comment128624923_72810473), it does work and the binding two ways works, I'm able to check and uncheck the selection.

But with data coming from the db. When I try to link the data coming from fetch outside the onMount, I get the error that no length for {finalgroupit} and {finalgroupit} log shows that {finalgroupit} is empty when I put it outside onMount

```
finalgroupit = Object.fromEntries(displayoptions.map(g => [g.groupheader,  []]));
```

When I put it inside the onMount, length is there but the binding doesn't work. It's hard to explain so I created a video screenshot. It's on youtube so it is safe to view it [Here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Vgng3_AlZc) As you can see I keep clicking to uncheck the selection but it doesn't become unchecked. That is the two ways binding, right? Any solution. Is there something I don't get about onMount or await that is causing this effect? I'm missing something about svelte.

---

if I do this

```
<script>    
    $: optiongroups = []
    
    onMount(async () => {
      optiongroups =  [
           {
            groupname : "exactly1",
            grouplimit : 1,
            id : 123,
            optionitems : [
              {
                name : "One",
                price : 1
              },
              {
                name : "Two",
                price : 2
              },
              {
                name : "Three",
                price : 3
              },
              {
                name : "Four",
                price : 4
              }
            ]
    
           },
           {
            groupname : "exactly2",
            grouplimit : 2,
            id : 369,
            optionitems : [
              {
                name : "2-One",
                price : 22
              },
              {
                name : "2-Two",
                price : 44
              },
              {
                name : "2-Three",
                price : 66
              },
              {
                name : "2-Four",
                price : 88
              }
            ]
    
           }
       ]
    })
    checkresults = Object.fromEntries(optiongroups.map(g => [g.groupname, []]));

</script>
```

Then this give me error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').

Isn't assignment triggers reactivity? and when I assign `optiongroups` with the data inside `onMount`, it should reevaluate the map outside? If the component is not mounted yet, I get the error, then how do I make that statement with the `map()` triggers only when the component is mounted? I think this is the issue.

Comment: Can you replace the part of the code that fetches the data with the result and create a full example that reproduces the issue? As long as the code is still structured the same way (data being set in `onMount`), the result should be equivalent and interchangeable with your real use case. (If you want to make sure it is asynchronous, throw in a `setTimeout` call.)

Comment: `finalgroupit = finalgroupit` is redundant, you have an assignment on the line above. Also would not do `finalgroupit = displayoptions` if you change it right after that anyway.

Comment: @H.B. setTimeout inside onMount after the I get the data?

Comment: Inside `onMount`, when setting the fake/constant data, to simulate the delay you would get from an actual fetch.

Comment: onMount(()=>setTimeout(() => {
      data...
    }, timeout);)

Comment: Yes, something like that, with the concrete data that demonstrates the issue, so people can just put that in the REPL if they want to. Ideally the code should be as minimal as possible but still self-contained. (See also [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: Your edit only provides partial code which does not work together with the rest. Some variables are missing/named differently. `checkresults` is not marked as reactive (`$: ...`), so it will not reevalute. You can probably do something like `$: checkresults = optiongroups == null ? [] : Object.fromEntries(...);`

Comment: I would recommend working out an example directly in the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/) and then only include that code in its entirety in your question. Optionally save the REPL and link to it as well.

Comment: I'll. I can't thank you enough for your help. If I can send you a crypto coin for your help I would if you're interested.